# Spark 1.6 vs spark 2.0 productivity

Tags: apache-spark

Databricks team has talked a lot about why spark 2.x is faster than 1.6.
But why operating on DataFrames in spark 2.x it can produce lower level bytecode? Why was it impossible with RDD API?

Also why is it so important to make Tungsten only from 2.0? What's wrong with doing it in spark 1.6?

[Spark 2.0 impruvments](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html)

Answer (score -1):

- For starters the first "Tungsten" optimizations have been introduced in Spark 1.4 and extended in 1.5 and 1.6.
- Spark 2.0 introduces backward incompatible changes which wouldn't be acceptable in 1.x due to project management policy.
- Structured data and restricted language requires simpler optimization rules. This is why linear algebra libraries or relational databases feature very aggressive optimizations, and your-arbitrary-code doesn't.

  It is impossible with RDD API for the same reason why your-favorite-compiler™ doesn't apply the same optimizations out-of-the-box. It is close to mpossible to do it right (have you noticed that code used with `Dataframe` has to be deterministic and has to contribute to execution plan, otherwise will be eliminated?).